# Obtener coordenadas GPS

Tags: arduino, gps

Actualmente tengo un [modulo 808](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B072FCFGDL).
Mi consulta es si para obtener la ubicación GPS con este modulo necesito solo usar los comandos `AT`, o puedo utilizar librerías como `TinyGPS`.

Actualmente tengo este código:

```
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>
#include <TinyGPS.h>

long lat,lon;
SoftwareSerial SIM808(7, 8);

TinyGPS gps;

void setup(){
  Serial.begin(19200);
  SIM808.begin(19200);
  Serial.print("GPS START");
}

void loop() {
  gps.encode(SIM808.read());
  gps.get_position(&lat, &lon);
  Serial.print("Position: ");
  Serial.print("lat "); Serial.prntln(lat);
  Serial.print("lon "); Serial.prntln(lon);
  delay(500);
}
```

Pero no logro que me de las coordenadas bien, y no sé si es porque solo con comandos `AT` funcionan.

Comment: Que significa: `no logro que me de las coordenadas bien`, eso es muy ambiguo, podrias explicar y mostrar la salida que obtienes, y la que debes obtener.

Comment: Me devuelve.

lat: 9999999
lon: 99999999

Comment: ¿Dónde estás poniendo la antena del módulo GPS? Es importante que esté en un sitio donde vea el cielo, si lo pones dentro de tu habitación cerca de una ventana podrá conectarse a los satélites pero tardará mucho. Con TinyGPS puedes utilizarlo no es más que una librería que parsea los mensajes NMEA. Mucho ánimo con tu proyecto :)

Answer (score 1):

Yo he realizado pruebas con la sim 808 bajo techo y no tengo problemas
Recomiendo uses primero los comandos AT para verificar el funcionamiento de tu tarjeta.

realizar los comandos de verificación de tu pin

```
AT+CPIN?
AT+CPIN=XXXX LAS "X" SON TU NÚMERO PIN DE LA SIM CELULAR
AT+IPR=19200
AT+CMGF=1 ACTIVA MODO TEXTO
AT+CMGR=1 ACTIVA RECEPTOR DE MENSAJES
AT+CNMI=2,2,0,0 ACTIVA VISUALIZACION DE MENSAJES
AT+ CGPSPWR=1 ACT GPS ORI
AT+CGNSTST=1 ACT GPS OCCI
AT+CGPSSTATUS?
AT+CGNSINF
```